# Issue with Displaying contact photos in Ionic

Tags: html, css, image, ionic-framework, contacts

I have the following code:

```
<ion-img style="

  float:left;    
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 20px;

" width="40" height="40" src="{{contact.photos}}"></ion-img>
```

And

```
this.contact.find(["displayName", "phoneNumbers", "photos"], {multiple: true}).then((contacts) => {
 for (var i=0 ; i < contacts.length; i++){
    var contact = {};
    if (contacts[i].photos != null){

      contact["photos"] = contacts[i].photos[0].value;

    }else{
      contact["photos"] = "../../assets/download";
    }

  }      
 }
 })
```

When the contact info has no photo, the default "download" is displayed but when the contact has a photo, it is not displayed and the image is just gray. What is the issue?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: I want the photo from contacts to display (Its a flower) but it just turns out blank.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the page to see what gets printed?